# How to fix: error: '<filename>' does not have a commit checked out fatal: adding files failed

Tags: reactjs, git

When creating a repository for a React project that should include frontend and backend, git doesn't allow me to add frontend folder.

This is the message:

error: 'frontend/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed

Any clue of what can I try to solve it?

Comment: With-out seeing more of your project it's difficult to help. Do you have a gitignore file? Can you please add the steps how you created your project, so it is possible to re-create your issue?

Comment: Is `frontend` a git repository by itself? Does it have `frontend/.git/`?

Comment: It's a project created direct with react, it contains already a .gitignore that I haven't touched it. But besides that I don't see a .git . Should I create this? I don't understand the question, sorry, I'm kind of new to it, but have already worked with git in several other projects and never got this error. It just happens when I do a react project, specific with the frontend folder

Comment: Backend and frontend supposed to be in the same repo, not in separate ones. Frontend didn't have a separate repo, it was local on  my machine, and I dragged it into the repo folder. Than I tried to do the same as I did for the backend: git add . / git commit -m "message"/ git push. But with frontend it desn't allow me to do git add.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

It had indeed create automatically a new repo/ subrepo... a .git file, but it was invisible. I asked to removed it anyway with: "rm -rf .git" inside of my frontend folder and it worked.

thank you all for your help!